# How to pass 'this' object to callback function which is called in a function using protocol apply

Tags: javascript, callback, this

main function as below, which will cause 'setState' is not a valid property exception.

```
componentWillMount = function () {
    api.daysOfMonth(this, this.props.month, this.props.year, function (ds) {
        var days = [];
        ds.forEach(function (jsonDay) {
            var day =  {date: jsonDay.date, inRange: jsonDay.inRange};
            days.push(day);
        });

        this.setState({ daysOfMonth: days });
  });
```

snippet of api.js is below.
The main function call Api.daysOfMonth(...), Api.daysOfMonth will use a global object to invoke a ajax method and call the callback function using protocol apply, the callback function is pass in from main function as above script.

```html
ApiImpl = (function () {
                function ApiImpl() { }
                
                ApiImpl.prototype.invoke = function (callerObj, callback, action) {
                    var params = [];
                    for (var _i = 3; _i < arguments.length; _i++) {
                        params[_i - 3] = arguments[_i];
                    }

                    params.push(callback); //push callback function into params, so object of QWebChannel can callback the function after execute the 'action'
                    
                    if (typeof window['api'] === 'undefined') {
                        new QWebChannel(qt.webChannelTransport, function (channel) {
                            window['api'] = channel.objects.api;
                           
                            var func = window['api'][action].bind(callerObj); 
                            return func.apply(callerObj, params); //here goes error
                        });
                    }
                    
                    var func = window['api'][action].bind(callerObj);
                    return func.apply(callerObj, params); //here goes error
                };
                return ApiImpl;
            }());
            Api = (function () {
                function Api() {
                }
                Api.daysOfMonth = function (callerObj, month, year, callback) {
                    this.impl.invoke(callerObj, callback, 'daysOfMonth', month, year);
                };
                return Api;
            }());
            Api.impl = new ApiImpl();
            exports_1("Api", Api);
```

Comment: What do you want `this` to be? `jsonDay`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this does answer your question, the reason is because `.bind()` binds `this` of the newly created function to the one your passed as the first argument.

```
componentWillMount = function () {
    api.daysOfMonth(this, this.props.month, this.props.year, function (ds) {
        var days = [];
        ds.forEach(function (jsonDay) {
            var day =  {date: jsonDay.date, inRange: jsonDay.inRange};
            days.push(day);
        });

        this.setState({ daysOfMonth: days });
  }.bind(this));
```

See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

Note that if you write es6, you can use arrow function to do the same thing.

```
componentWillMount = function () {
    api.daysOfMonth(this, this.props.month, this.props.year, (ds) => {
        var days = [];
        ds.forEach(function (jsonDay) {
            var day =  {date: jsonDay.date, inRange: jsonDay.inRange};
            days.push(day);
        });

        this.setState({ daysOfMonth: days });
  });
```

In short, `this` in an arrow function is lexical scope that means `this` is guaranteed to be the same `this` where the arrow function is defined.

See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Yeah, your solution goes OK! I put bind() in the internal function, which I should put in my main function. Thanks a lot.